# Addition of two sets... How to proceed

Tags: python, set-theory

Consider the two sets:-
{9,87} and {1,2,3,45}. Here I don't mean union but addition which shall produce the output as all possible additions of two element combos such that each element is from a different set.

So the answer I should get is:-
{9+1,9+2,9+3,9+45,87+1,87+2,87+3,87+45}

How may I proceed with this type of unique addition of two sets in a continuous space? I tried with two circles and found the expression extremely difficult....

Comment: You're likely looking at nested loops, or using itertools. Do you know how to iterate over a set, e.g. something like `for element in set1`?

Comment: What do you mean with continuous space and circles? Your example is good for illustrating what kind of addition you mean, but you should also show your actual kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
set3 = set()

for item1 in set1:
    for item2 in set2:
        set3.add(item1+item2)
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I proceed if each set is actually an equation of a circle (I have to add two different circles in the manner above)...

Comment: @S_Banerjee Your example had `9+1,9+2,...` as the desired answer.  If simple addition isn't enough, please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` can help produce the desired set. `member1` is an element from `set1`, and `member2` is an element from `set2`. `itertools.product` produces the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two sets -- specifically, all possible tuples where the first element is a member of `set1` and the second element is a member of `set2`.

```py
import itertools

set1 = {9,87}
set2 = {1,2,3,45}
print({member1 + member2 for member1, member2 in itertools.product(set1, set2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set comprehension to achieve this

```
x = {9,87}
y = {1,2,3,45}
z = {i+j for i in x for j in y}
```